# Why can't the size of stack be determined at compile time?

Tags: c, compilation, stack

I have read that the size of heap and stack cannot be computed at compile time and needs to be evaluated at runtime.

I can think of this code which allocates heap based on user input and needs the runtime:

```
int size;
scanf("%d", &size):
void *ptr= malloc(size);
```

But aren't all the stack variables already present in a function? given their data type (`int`, `char`, `long` etc.) why can't the compiler calculate the size?

Comment: `scanf("%d", size):` ==> `scanf("%d", &size);`

Comment: VLAs, `alloca`, assembly code that modifies the stack pointer.

Comment: Are you talking about the size of a specific stack frame, or the whole stack?

Comment: Each function call requires certain stack use. Now think about whether it is possible to know at compile time how many times every function will be called and how deep every call stack is. It is not possible because some inputs are not known until runtime.

Comment: ...it may be impossible for the compiler to know how many times a recursive function will be called.

Comment: .....external library and system calls.....

Comment: ...multiple stacks....

Comment: ...interrupts and callbacks....

Answer (score 1):

With C99, it is possible to create Variable length array (VLA) on the stack. Those arrays will have dynamic size based on runtime parameters, or calculated expressions. In those cases, not possible to calculate stack size until runtime.

For example:

```
int f(int n) {
    // Size based on input
    int x[n] ;

    // Dynamic size
    int m = n+5000 ;
    int y[mm] ;

};
```

Needless to say that if the allocation of a single function can not be calculated, it is not possible to calculate the stack size of a complete program

Comment: That's true and a good point. But there are also other (arguably stronger) reasons such as exact function calls being unknown until runtime.

Comment: ye but doesn't the compiler know the value of `n`?

Comment: @josh If 'n' is read from the outsize (scanf, ...) the compiler will not know the size of N.

Comment: @Josh The compiler is not that smart.

Answer (score 0):

Stack memory is allocated at the entry of the function. That's why the stack size depends on the sequence of function calls, which is not defined at compile time (e.g. any `if`, `switch` can change the function call sequence)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't the size of stack be determined at compile time?
>   But aren't all the stack variables already present in a function?

2 things that prevent compile time stack size computation:

[Variable logic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) allow for a run-time determined amount of memory usage of the "stack". Other non-standard functions like `alloca()` do so also.

*Recursion* allows for a run-time determined depth of function calls and thus a run-time determined amount of memory usage even if each function memory usage was constant. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548259/why-cant-the-size-of-stack-be-determined-at-compile-time/59549377#comment105265597_59548259)

---

Were it not for these 2 and maybe [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548259/why-cant-the-size-of-stack-be-determined-at-compile-time/59549377?noredirect=1#comment105326707_59549377),  code could be analysed at compile time to determine stack usage, max function depth and then possible not even use a "stack" in classic sense, storing all "stack" memory in a fixed space.  Some compilers provide for this. [e.g.](https://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36099)

Comment: C and other languages allow variable parameter lists (i.e. `function foo(int x, ...)`), so you'd have to eliminate that as well. And for the compiler to compute a max call depth, it would need full knowledge of all external function calls and their dependencies. It would have trouble with things like passing callback function pointers to other functions. Probably more things we'd have to restrict. I think it becomes a "theoretically possible," but impractical, exercise. But probably not on the order of the halting problem.

Comment: @JimMischel As the question is tagged C, and C, by default does not allow  other languages, disallowing  other languages is not needed.  I suspect your idea about call back function applies.  This is not only theoretically possible, but done with some today's compiler's as given in the example link.

Answer (score 0):

recursive functions need the stack size to be dynamic I believe.
And also some versions of C allow variable length arrays

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).